# TSQL: Relational Division with Remainder (RDWR)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, relational-division

I have mapping table `CandidatesSkills` which holds the mapping between candidate and the skills they possess. Then I have another table `JobRequirements` that maps jobs and required skills for that jobs.
A candidate can apply to a job if he possesses ALL the required skills for that job. A candidate can have extra skills. Given `CandiateID` I want to find all the jobs that candidate can apply.

I think this is Relational Division with Remainder in SQL. And there is an [article here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/)  that explains the exact issue. *(Note: the article tries to find all Candidates who has ALL skills for the given job. My problem is exactly opposite. I am trying to find all Jobs that matches with given Candidate's skill)*

**Candidate's Skills**
[image]

**Job to required skills mapping**
[image]

based on the dataset, the query below should return JobID 2,3 and 5

Here my SQL (based on Peter Larsson (PESO) Solution for RDNR/RDWR)

```
DECLARE @CandidateID INT = 1

SELECT JobID 
FROM        
(
    SELECT jr.JobID
        ,cnt=SUM(CASE WHEN jr.SkillID = c.SkillID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        ,Items=COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.JobRequirements AS jr
    CROSS JOIN dbo.CandidatesSkills  AS c    
    WHERE c.CandidateID = @CandidateID
    GROUP BY jr.JobID, jr.SkillID
) d
GROUP BY JobID
HAVING  SUM(cnt) = MIN(Items)
    AND MIN(cnt) >= 0;
```

However, query does not return anything. Trying to find what's wrong with my query

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2bb40/9)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
DECLARE @CandidateID INT = 1;

with cj as
(
  select cs.CandidateId, 
         jr.JobId, 
         count(*) over (partition by jr.JobId, cs.CandidateId) skillsPosessed,
         (select count(*) from JobRequirements where JobId = jr.JobId) skillsRequired
  from CandidatesSkills cs
  join JobRequirements jr
    on cs.SkillId = jr.SkillId
)
select distinct cj.CandidateId, cj.JobId
from cj
where cj.skillsPosessed = cj.skillsRequired
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you doing **relational division with multiple divisors**. In other words, you are dividing *each set* of `JobRequirements` *per each* `JobID`, by the `CandidateSkills` of that candidate.

In this case, a `LEFT JOIN` solution is much simpler

```sql
DECLARE @CandidateID INT = 1;

SELECT jr.JobID
    ,Skills = COUNT(c.SkillID)
    ,Requirements = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.JobRequirements AS jr
LEFT JOIN dbo.CandidatesSkills  AS c ON c.SkillID = jr.SkillID
    AND c.CandidateID = @CandidateID
GROUP BY jr.JobID
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(c.SkillID);
```

What this does is left-join the candidate's skills to the requirements. We then simply count up all the `Requirements` for the `JobID`, and ensure it is equal to the number of matches.

Another way to write this is

```sql
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN c.SkillID IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

In other words: the number of *non-matches* should be zero.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2bb40/42)